# How should I use the delete in this occasion c++

Tags: c++, delete-operator

So this is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define MAX 5
#define STR_LENGTH 40

void main()
{
    char *p_str[MAX];

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        *(p_str+i) = new char(STR_LENGTH);
        cout << "Please enter a string:  ";
        cin >> *(p_str+i);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        cout << *(p_str+i) << endl;
        delete (p_str+i);
    }

}
```

And that last line in there, I have that delete, but it breaks when it gets there, any ideas how to solve it please?

Comment: `main` must have a return type of `int`. Anyway, just use `std::array<std::string, MAX>`, or a `std::vector` to get rid of the silly maximum.

Comment: The `std::string` is critical.  There's really no reasonable way you can safely read into a `char[]`.  (And what's with the `*(p_str+i)`, instead of the idiomatic `p_str[i]`?)

Answer (score 8):

`new char(STR_LENGTH)` doesn't do what you think it does. It allocates memory for a single char, initialized to the value of `STR_LENGTH`. As written, you have a buffer overrun. Make it `new char[STR_LENGTH]`.

Now that you are allocating an array, you should deallocate it with `delete [] (p_str+i);`, or a bit more concisely, `delete [] p_str[i];`

Comment: Of course, even then, if the user ever happens to enter more than 39 characters, it will break.  The only correct answer here is to use `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: Its not my code, in my work I need to correct a code, and make it work with the minimum of changes possible, else I woudl totally use std::string